# Mark changes as already merged or deliberately ignored with hg pull/push/merge/graft?

Tags: mercurial, merge, dvcs, cherry-pick

I'm transitioning to Mercurial from Subversion, where I'm used to using svnmerge.py to track changes that have already been merged, or which have been blocked from being merged:

```
# Mark change 123 as having already been merged; it will not be merged again, even if a range
# that contains it is subsequently specified.
svnmerge.py merge -M -r123
#
# Block change 326 from being considered for merges.
svnmerge.py merge -X -r326
#
# Show changes that are available for merging from the source branch.
svnmerge.py avail
#
# Do a catchall merge of the remaining changes.  Neither change 123 nor change 326 will be
# considered for merging.
svnmerge.py merge
```

I want to be able to do something similar for hg pull/push/merge/graft, so that if I know that I never want to merge a given change, I can just block it from consideration, making subsequent cherry-picking, merging, etc., into a more fire-and-forget affair.  I have done a lot of googling, but have not found a way to do this.

There also appears to be no way to view a list of as-yet-ungrafted changes.

As I'm often tidying up after other developers and helping them with their merges, it's immensely helpful to be able to do these kinds of things, which one might well consider "inverse cherry-picking;" i.e., marking changes that you do NOT want to merge, and then doing a bulk merge of the remainder.

Comment: MG has your answers below, he TL;DR version being: DAG based systems (Mercurial, Git, etc.) do a great job of keeping track of what has been merged in, and so long as you avoid cherrypicking (which neither git nor Mercurial handle well -- by design) then what has already been merged and what needs to be merged just sorts itself out.

Comment: Alas, in $REALWORLD, you end up with a branch for current development and one or more branches representing stabilization-for-pending-release and released-and-in-the-field, and there may well be intentional divergences within those branches.  You want mundane bug fixes to flow easily from branch to branch, but you do not; e.g., want new features to flow to stabilization or support branches, and you do not want, say, configuration changes that work around a bug fixed in the current dev branch to flow back up from support branches.

Comment: If I'm living in a word other than $REALWORLD I need better fantasies. The situation you describe works just great in a non-transplant mode.  Try to catch a video of the fogbugz world tour for 2011 where @bmp walks you through merging fixing forward into multiple released versions all without using named branches or transplant.  So long as you make a fix a child of the revision that added it (which `hg bisect` makes easy to find) you can use `hg merge` to pull it forward into any release or pending release without bringing *any* other changesets with it.

Comment: I've added a bit to the already long answer... @Ry4an is right when he says that you can get a great workflow going if you know the rules of three-way merging and thus merge forward, not backwards.

Comment: I don't doubt that you are correct, and that, for a conscientious, expert hg user, your method will work.  I have a little hope, as the SCM people are likely going to be the only people doing wholesale (i.e., non-graft) merges between multiple lines of development.  I had hoped that there would be something that I could use to ease the process for "naive" hg users, but it appears that there is none.  There's also the case of "PITA Fred," who manages to screw up everything.  Every organization has one of those, and developing processes that limit the damage he can do is important.

Answer (score 9):

DAG-based systems like Mercurial ans Git are all or nothing: when you merge two branches, you do a three-way merge of the common ancestor and the two branches.

The three-way merge is **only** concerned with the final stage of each branch. For instance, it doesn't matter if you make your changes in 10 it 1000 steps — the merge result will be the same.

This implies that the only way to ignore a changeset is to back it out before the merge:

```
$ hg backout BAD
```

That will cancel the changeset on the branch, making it appear that it was never made from the perspective of the three-way merge.

If you have a whole branch that you want to merge, but ignore, then you can do a *dummy merge*:

```
$ hg merge --tool internal:local --non-interactive
$ hg revert --all --rev .
```

That goes through the merge, but reverts back to the old state before committing.

---

The best advice I can give you is to structure your workflow so that the above backouts aren't necessary. This means committing a bugfix on the **oldest applicative branch**. If a bug is found while creating feature X, then use `hg bisect` to figure out when the bug was introduced. Now updated back to the oldest branch where you still want to fix the bug:

```
$ hg update 2.0
# fix bug
$ hg commit -m "Fixed issue-123"
```

then merge the bugfix into all later branches:

```
$ hg update 2.1
$ hg merge 2.0
$ hg commit -m "Merge with 2.0 to get bugfix for issue-123"

$ hg update 2.2
$ hg merge 2.1
$ hg commit -m "Merge with 2.1 to get bugfix for issue-123"
```

If the bugfix no longer applies, then you should **still merge**, but throw away the unrelated changes:

```
$ hg update 3.0
$ hg merge 2.2 --tool internal:local --non-interactive
$ hg revert --all --rev .
$ hg commit -m "Dummy merge with 2.2"
```

That ensures that you can always use

```
$ hg log -r "::2.2 - ::3.0"
```

to see changesets on the 2.2 branch that haven't been merged into 3.0 yet.